# How to Call "Add to Home" Activity in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-source

On Android devices when you click or long press on an empty area of a home screen, the Add to Home Activity/dialog opens up allowing you to choose from different options to put on the home screen.

I have a notification that goes off at the status bar, what I want to do is when that notification is clicked I want to open the Add to Home Activity.

The notification is working fine.

Is there an activity name.class that I could set as the target of the notification when clicked?

I checked [Android Launcher source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher/+/master/src/com/android/launcher/Launcher.java#1688).

I found this:

```
    if (mWorkspace.allowLongPress()) {
1747             if (cellInfo.cell == null) {
1748                 if (cellInfo.valid) {
1749                     // User long pressed on empty space
1750                     mWorkspace.setAllowLongPress(false);
1751                     showAddDialog(cellInfo);
1752                 }
1753             } else {
1754                 if (!(cellInfo.cell instanceof Folder)) {
1755                     // User long pressed on an item
1756                     mWorkspace.startDrag(cellInfo);
1757                 }
1758             }
1759         }
1760         return true;
```

Most certainly `showAddDialog(cellInfo)` brings up the Add to Home screen.

Any ideas on how do I go about implementing this for my requirement above.

Comment: You realize that the user is free to use a different home screen, right? And how this works is probably dependant on the home screen.

Answer (score 0):

To start an activity when you click the notification you can use some thing like below,

```
                   NotificationManager mNoficationManager;
            mNoficationManager = (NotificationManager) mCntxt.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            Intent intent1 = new Intent();
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName("YOURPACKAGE TO START","YOUR ACTIVIT TO BE STARTED");
    intent1.setComponent(comp);
    intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);


    /* SEND NOTIFICATION */
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(mCntxt, 0, intent1, 0);
    Notification n = new Notification();
    n.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    n.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    n.tickerText = "some text for tickering";
    mNoficationManager.notify(some int value for your notification id, n);

    int icon = mCntxt.getApplicationInfo().icon;
            Notification notification = new Notification(icon,"some text title",System.currentTimeMillis());
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(mCntxt, "Some text", " some text ", pi);

    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    mNoficationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Hope from this you can derive something to start "Add to Home Activity".